# How to bypass managed package from Test class

Tags: unit-test, managed-package, failing-tests

**Test Class :**

```
    Account ac = new Account();
    ac.Name = 'Test3';
    ac.Type = 'Corporate';
    ac.BillingCountry = 'DE';
    ac.BillingStreet = 'First line' + '\n' + 'Second Line';
    ac.BillingPostalCode='421301';
    ac.BillingCity='Kalyan';
    ac.BillingState='ABC';
    insert ac;
```

Inserting Account from Test class, Managed package will cause below Error:

**04:42:59.203 (8303356090)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, Access to entity 'geopointe__Geopointe_Setting__mdt' denied: Entity is not api accessible: []**

I searched "geopointe__Geopointe_Setting__mdt" in Org not able to find it and try to query it from Developer console received below error:

**sObject type 'geopointe__Geopointe_Setting__mdt' is not supported.**

Then I have verified installed package "GeoPoint (Managed)" causing this issue.

**How to bypass managed package in case of test class execution ,instead of doing uninstallation any other way?**

Comment: I would reach out to the vendor to see if they can suggest something to get past this issue. Are you inserting the Account as an Admin user?

Comment: @Mohit . Sure thank You. Inserting as an admin user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try to bypass the error,

1. Find out the permission sets that the Managed Package needs and assign them to user running the Test class.
2. Make sure your profile has access to the metadata types from the package

[image]

> If none of the above works because the custom metadata type is protected, I suggest reaching out to the vendor(Geo Pointe) so that they can suggest the fix or fix their code to not cause this issue.

Comment: Thanks. custom meta data is protected. So no luck